# Translation of "of which"

Tags: word-order, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> 23.5 billion kilograms of household-waste every year, of which 9.4 billion is recycled.

I wasn't really sure of the word for *of which*. My instinct was *von denen*, but a dictionary says *woran*.

> Im Vereinigten Königreich, gibts jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarde Kilo Hausmüll, von denen 9,4 Milliarden recycelt wird.

Is that right? Am I right in sending *wird* to the end of the sentence?

So after reading the responses, is this the best way to phrase?

> Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll an, wovon 9,4 Milliarden recycelt wird.

Comment: Im Vereinigten Königreich gibt es jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Kilogramm Haushaltsmüll, von denen 9,4 Milliarden rezykliert / recycelt werden.

Comment: *Wovon* is nicer.

Comment: Thanks. Is wovon especially formal/colloquial or will you hear it anywhere?

Comment: I would say is is a bit more formal, but you still can hear _wovon_ everywhere

Comment: I would say: "wovon 9,4 Milliarden recycelt _werden_.", because "9.4 Milliarden" is plural, cf. "Über eine halbe Million Tonnen Hausmüll pro Jahr werden im Müllheizkraftwerk Ruhleben thermisch behandelt" (http://www.bsr.de/9373.html)

Comment: @Iris Even if there are 23.5 bilion tons of trash, your 'wovon' points on 'den Hausmüll', where a plural does not exist.(Source [Wikitionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%BCll)

Comment: @inetphantom, I asked a own question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26767/tonnen-m%C3%BCll-plural-oder-singluar

Comment: @Ralph please do not misuse the comments to answer the question. Write an answer to answer the question instead.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to phrase is:

> In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, wovon 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.

The two verbs both refer to *n billions kilograms/ n million tons*, so they have to be plural! (see: ["Tonnen Müll" plural oder singular](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26767/tonnen-m%C3%BCll-plural-oder-singular/))

You could also say:
(but "wovon" is the better choice)

> In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, von denen 9,4 Millionen recycelt werden.

Some more explanations:

- the missing verb in your English reference: "anfallen" (accrue) is better than "geben" (there are), because it refers to the active process of producing trash.
- Großbritannien; UK; Vereiniges Königreich... all mean different things. Check your original English reference.
- 23.5 billions (23500000000000) in German are "23,5 Milliarden". So it is either "23,5 Milliarden Kilogramm" or "23,5 Millionen Tonnen"

Comment: Thanks. I know they are technically different things, but in this case the statistic I am using doesn't actually need to be accurate...

Comment: @Medi1Saif, ja klar. Ist jetzt korrigiert.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to phrase it. Here are my suggestions:

> - In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, **wovon** 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.
> - In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, **von denen** 9,4 Millionen recycelt werden.

Note you can replace Großbritanien with Vereinigte Köngireich, but this is less in use by saying for example:

> Im Vereinigten Königreich fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, wovon 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.

A simpler way to express the same sentence (this time expressed in kilogramms instead of tonnes) is:

> Im Vereinigten Königreich gibt es jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Kilo 
>    Hausmüll, von denen 9,4 Milliarden recycelt werden.

---

A bit off-topic but maybe helpful:
One could also express it with "zusammen kommen" or "sich sammeln" ...:

> - Im Vereinigten Königreich *kommen* jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll *zusammen*, wovon 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.
> - Im Vereinigten Königreich *sammeln sich* jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll, wovon 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.
> - Im Vereinigten Königreich *werden* jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll *gesammelt*, wovon 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.

---

But as you are rather looking for a translation for "of which": One could also use "aus denen" instead of "von denen" and "woraus" instead of "wovon"!

> - Im Vereinigten Königreich fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, *von denen* 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.
> - Im Vereinigten Königreich fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, *wovon* 9,4 Millionen (Tonnen) recycelt werden.

Answer (score -1):

The particular points you asked about are almost correct: *von denen* is pretty much the best choice except for being plural, *wird* belongs at the end of the dependent sentence, and "Kilo" is in accusative, not genitive.

However, there are other errors and a bit of ambiguity. First, the source phrase doesn't have a verb, so adding one in the German translation is inappropriate without knowing the context. (It seems you didn't post the entire source, because there's no mention of the UK there either.)

I'll assume the source is "In the UK, there's 23.5 billion kilograms of household-waste ..." since that fits the translation best.

The translation is

> Im Vereinigten Königreich gibt es jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Kilo Hausmüll, von dem 9,4 Milliarden recycelt wird.

Note:

- No comma after "Im Vereinigten Königreich".
- *Gibts* or rather *gibt's* is a colloquial contraction and inappropriate for formal writing.
- *Milliarden* needs to be plural.
- *Kilo* is not put into plural because it doesn't stand alone but rather modifies *Hausmüll*, which is uncountable.
- Since it is uncountable, the appropriate form to use in the dependent sentence is singular. Although plural (*von denen* combined with *werden* at the end) would not raise many eyebrows, singular is more correct.

More idiomatically, though, you wouldn't write *gibt es* at all; instead you would probably write "Das Vereinigte Königreich produziert jedes Jahr ...".

Comment: Some notes: 1. The colloquial _Kilo_ doesn’t seem to fit here, rather use _Kilogramm_. However, I think most German texts would use _Tonnen_ (1000 kg) for such a large mass. 2. The typical verb would be _anfallen_ (_… fallen jedes Jahr x Tonnen Müll an_). 3. As Jan already commented, _wovon_ is better than _von dem_ in this case. 4. „9,4 Milliarden“ requires a plural verb. 5. Instead of _recyceln_ or _rezyklieren_, you could use _wiederverwerten_. 6. Only an extremely formal text would use _Vereinigtes Königreich_. A newspaper would write _Großbritannien_.

Comment: So would this be the best way of wording?
Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Millionen Tonnen Hausmüll an, wovon 9,4 Millionen recycelt wird.

Comment: @chirlu With you with everything but the last point. If the newspaper just used *Großbritannien* and *England* it will move on to *Vereinigtes Königreich* due to synonymitis.

Comment: England, Großbritannien o. Vereinigtes Königreich sind 3 Paar Schuhe (England, Great Britain, United Kingdom). E+Sco+Wal=GB, GB+N.Irl.=UK. Da das Original nicht genannt wird können wir nur raten was richtig wäre. 9,4 Mio werden recycelt, der Hausmüll wird recycelt. 'Produziert' finde ich für ein Abfallprodukt auch weniger günstig, aber würde es im Normalfall wohl gar nicht weiter bemerken.

Comment: @user unknown: Wer _Großbritannien_ sagt, außerhalb eines spezifisch juristisch-formellen oder geographischen Kontexts, meint das _Vereinigte Königreich Großbritannien und Nordirland_. Es wäre andererseits eine Umfrage interessant, welcher Anteil der Deutschen den Begriff _Vereinigtes Königreich_ richtig zuordnen kann.

Comment: @chirlu: Es geht hier um den Müll, der anfällt, und da spielt es nun mal eine  Rolle ob mit Nordirland oder ohne. Den Stellen, die so was schätzen, ist soviel Differenzierung wohl nicht zuviel. Dass es Zeitungen, die Du liest, eher lax sehen, glaube ich Dir aber gerne, wenn Du das sagst.

Comment: @user unknown: Welche (deutschsprachigen) Zeitungen liest du denn, die vom _Vereinigten Königreich_ schreiben?