# "Tonnen Müll" plural oder singular

Tags: grammatical-number

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/translation-of-of-which) wirft bei mir eine neue auf:

Was ist richtig *wird* oder *werden*?

> Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll
> an, wovon 9,4 Milliarden recycelt **wird**.
>
> Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll
> an, wovon 9,4 Milliarden recycelt **werden**.

Ich weiß, dass *Müll* immer singular ist, aber trotzdem würde ich bei *23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll* den Plural verwenden, weil es sich das Verb meinem Verständnis nach auf *Tonnen* und nicht auf *Müll* bezieht

> ... wovon 9,4 Milliarden Tonnen recycelt werden. = Es werden 9.4 Tonnen recycelt.

Und ich scheine nicht die einzige zu sein:

> Über eine halbe Million Tonnen Hausmüll pro Jahr **werden** im
> Müllheizkraftwerk Ruhleben thermisch behandelt. ([BSR](http://www.bsr.de/9373.html))
>
> Jedes Jahr **landen** fast sieben Millionen Tonnen Plastikmüll in unseren
> Meeren und **bilden** teilweise gigantische Müllstrudel im Wasser
> ([WWF](http://www.wwf.de/themen-projekte/meere-kuesten/unsere-ozeane-versinken-im-plastikmuell/))

---

**Edit: Bezüglich Duplikat**

Ich denke es ist kein Duplikat zu: [»Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/eine-halbe-million-h%C3%A4user-wurde-zerst%C3%B6rt), da es ja dort ja speziell um "**Eine** halbe Million  Häuser" geht.
Die Antwort

> Zwei Millionen Häuser wurden zerstört.

zu der Frage würde meine These, dass Plural angebracht ist zwar stützen, aber entkräftet nicht den Einwand von @inetphantom in den [Kommentaren](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26707/translation-of-of-which), dass Müll immer singular sei: "Even if there are 23.5 bilion tons of trash, your 'wovon' points on 'den Hausmüll', where a plural does not exist.(Source [Wikitionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%BCll)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [»Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.«](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/eine-halbe-million-h%c3%a4user-wurde-zerst%c3%b6rt)

Comment: Guter Punkt wegen des Duplikats. Closevote zurückgezogen.

Comment: Doch, die Dublette behandelt genau den entscheidenden Punkt: Man kann entweder die Zahlenangabe („eine halbe Million“, „23,5 Tonnen“) oder den Hauptbegriff („Häuser“, „Hausmüll“) als Kern des Subjekts auffassen; und deren Numerus kann verschieden sein, egal in welcher Anordnung.

Comment: @chirlu *Im Neubaugebiet wird 25 neue Häuser gebaut?* Ich bitte Dich...

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: _25_: Mehrzahl. _Häuser_: Mehrzahl. Kein verschiedener Numerus, keine Auswahl; dein Popanz-Beispiel ist daher falsch.

Comment: Meine Antwort zur anderen Frage beantwortet auch diese hier. Auch wenn ich es nicht explizit aufzähle, ist es dennoch enthalten. Stichwörter: Kongruenzregel, Kern des Subjekts. Ich habe daher auch für Close gevotet.

Comment: @Em1, ich habe mir nochmal deine Antwort durchgelesen und dort KEINE Antwort auf meine Frage gefunden. Allerdings dann in deiner verlinkten Quelle.

Comment: (1) "Es gibt eine Kongruenzregel, die besagt, dass Subjekt und Prädikat in Einklang sein müssen.", (2) "Der Numerus wird vom Kern bestimmt", (3) "Der Kern ist Eine halbe Million, welche den Singular verlangt.". Auf dein Beispiel angewandt, müssen wir den Teil (3) ändern: "Kern des Subjekts ist 23,5 Milliarden (oder meinetwegen 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen—das macht hier keinen Unterschied), welche den Plural verlangt". Also aufgrund Kern im Plural und Kongruenz zwischen Subjekt und Verb, steht Verb im Plural.

Comment: Es war mir aber nicht sicher, ob 23.5 Millarden der Kern war und ob man die Regel, die sich auf einen Singular-Fall bezieht auch einfach auf einen Plural-Fall anwenden kann. @Em1, deine Quelle sagt außerdem, das das Verb im singular möglich wäre.

Comment: @Iris Dort wird aber zwischen grammatischen und inhaltlichem Subjekt unterschieden. Dasselbe gilt auch für den Fall mit der "halben Millionen Häuser", dort ist es halt nur genau andersrum. Von der Grammatik her, ist nur eines richtig.

Comment: @Em1, nachdem dein Kommentar mich erst total verwirrt hab, hat es gerade klick gemacht und ich denke ich hab es jetzt verstanden.

Comment: Einfach, m.E.: wenn schon anfangs der Plural benutzt wird (fallen an), muss der Rest auch Plural sein (werden).

Comment: @chirlu: **eine** Million, also Einzahl. Dass das eine Million Häuser ist, ist da egal.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Ich empfehle, erst einmal die restlichen Kommentare und die Antworten zu lesen, bevor du sagst, daß alles ganz eindeutig ist.

Comment: @chirlu: was meinst du? Also, der erste Satzteil benutzt die Mehrzahl, also sollte der zweite das auch, vor allem well es Millarden **sind**. Allerdings, zum anderen Kommentar: wenn es **eine** Million ist, sollte man m.E. die Einzahl benutzen. Es gibt gewiss gute Gründe für die Mehrzahl (weil 1.000.000 > 1), aber die überzeugen mich nicht so sehr wie die Tatsache, dass es **eine** Million ist. Sprache ist nicht Mathe.

Comment: Übrigens: "23,5", "Millionen" und "Tonnen" sind alle Plural, also suche dir was aus. Hier ist es m.E. unstrittig, das die Mehrzahl benutzt werden soll, vor allem wenn anfangs schon die Mehrzahl (*anfallen*) benutzt wird. Einzahl wäre Blödsinn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entscheidend bei diesem Beispiel ist die Tatsache, dass »*Müll*« ein Singularetantum ist, das nicht in den Plural gesetzt werden kann. Aus dem Versuch, *Müll* durch ein Wort zu ersetzen, das einen Plural hat (wie z.B. Apfel-Äpfel), wird man daher keine sinnvollen Erkenntnisse ziehen können. Da muss man schon in die richtige Kiste greifen, nämlich in jene, in der sich die Namen von nicht zählbaren Stoffen befinden:

Namen von nicht zählbaren Stoffen:

- Erde
- Wasser
- Luft
- Milch
- Honig
- Sand
- Gas
- <sub>usw.</sub>

Zu den Singulariatantum gehören auch andere Wörter, darunter lustigerweise auch das Wort »Plural«.

Man kann von den meisten dieser Wörter zwar den Plural (aber keine <del>*Plurale*</del>!) bilden, der hat dann aber eine andere Bedeutung. Mit »Sanden« meint man »Sand-Arten«, aber Sand und noch mehr Sand ist noch immer *ein Sand*. Ähnlich ist es mit den anderen hier aufgelisteten Begriffen. Falls ein Plural existiert, bezeichnet dieser mehrere verschiedene Arten des jeweiligen Stoffes, aber nicht eine größere Menge.

Und der *Müll* gehört auch zu dieser Gruppe. Gibt man zu einem Müll noch einen Müll, hat man am Ende nicht *zwei <del>Mülle</del>* sondern noch immer nur *einen Müll*. (Nimmt man einen Apfel und noch einen Apfel, hat man aber *zwei Äpfel*, und genau das macht den Unterschied aus).

Will man den Beispielsätzen also mit Vergleichen beikommen, dann darf man den Müll nicht durch einen Apfel (oder durch mehrere Äpfel) ersetzen, sondern durch Sand, Wasser, Honig oder einen anderen Begriff aus der oben beschriebenen richtigen Kiste.

---

Für die Fragestellung ist das aber irrelevant, wie in anderen Antworten schon ausgearbeitet wurde:

> Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen *Hausmüll* an, wovon **9,4 Milliarden** recycelt **werden**.

Das Verb »*werden*« bezieht sich nämlich nicht auf den Müll, nicht auf die Tonnen, und auch nicht auf irgend etwas anderes aus dem Hauptsatz, sondern auf das Subjekt jenes Relativsatzes, in dem es selbst steht. Und da kommen nur »9,4 Milliarden« in Frage. Und nachdem sowohl die Milliarden im Plural stehen, als auch die Zahl (9,4) von 1 verschieden ist, bleibt dem Verb nichts anderes übrig, als auch im Plural zu stehen.

Ersetzt man dieses Subjekt durch eines, das im Singular steht, muss auch das Verb im Singular stehen, selbst wenn man nun den Singular-Müll durch Plural-Äpfel ersetzt (weil Müll bzw. Äpfel keinen grammatischen Bezug zum Verb »werden« haben):

> Im Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen *Äpfel* an, wovon **nur eine Tonne** recycelt **wird**.

Insofern ist der Einwand, die Frage sei ein Duplikat einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24766/1487), durchaus berechtigt, denn in der verlinkten Frage wird genau untersucht, wann ein Verb im Plural stehen muss, und wann nicht.

Im Beispielsatz könnte man aber für das Verb »*fallen*« diskutieren, ob es im richtigen Numerus steht, denn dieses Verb bezieht sich auf »*23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll*« (grammatisch vergleichbar mit »zwei Liter Milch«), und hier könnte man den Singular-Status von *Müll* (oder *Milch*) ins Treffen führen.

Aber zum einen wurde diese Frage nicht gestellt, und zum anderen wäre auch hier die Antwort, dass das Verb im Plural stehen muss, wobei die Begründung auch hier in den Antworten zur [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24766/1487) nachgelesen werden kann.

Comment: Danke. Genau so wollte ich das auch sagen. :-D

Comment: Nur zu deinen ersten, irrelevanten Ausführungen: Sagst du also auch: _Es wurde 5 Gläser Wasser getrunken?_ Oder nicht doch eher _Es wurden 5 Gläser Wasser getrunken?_

Comment: Einige Beispiele aus Deiner obigen Aufzählung sind etwas unglücklich gewählt, weil es dafür eben doch - teilweise mit anderer Bedeutung - einen Plural gibt. Für Gas beispielsweise: Wasserstoff, Sauerstoff und Stickstoff sind *Gase*. Auf die Erwähnung des analogen Falls der Elemente, die man *Seltene Erden* nennt, verzichte ich aber, denn: Stille Wasser sind tief ;-)

Comment: Tonne ist aber kein Singulare tantum. Eine Tonne, zwei Tonnen, dreihunderttausend Tonnen.

Comment: Hmmm... Ich behaupte, die Wörter "Tonnen", "Millionen", "Milliarden" und "Häuser" sind Plurale. Ein Plural, mehrere Plurale.

Comment: Da Müll zu den Singularetantum gehört kann man auch die Form "ein Müll" nicht bilden (außer in "Was ist das für ein Müll!"), sprich, zu einem sprachlichen Müll nicht noch einen sprachlichen Müll zugeben, sondern bloß zu Sprachmüll weiteren Sprachmüll hinzumüllen und hat im Ergebnis großen Sprachmüll. Dass wir im Land der Mülltrenner Müll unterschiedlicher Art und damit Mülle haben, hast du dankenswerter Weise schon benannt.

Answer (score 7):

*Werden* ist korrekt, denn aufgrund der Zahl (z. B. neun Milliarden) ist ersichtlich, dass es mehrere sind, somit wird das Verb im Plural verwendet.

Comment: Mehrere was? Mehrere Milliarden oder mehrere Tonnen?

Answer (score 5):

Ich finde, die Frage beantwortet sich bereits aus der ersten Hälfte des Satzes

> In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll an

Auch hier wird offensichtlich der Plural verwendet (und von Dir auch nicht hinterfragt), so dass es nur konsequent (und meiner Meinung nach wegen der Mehrzahl von neun Milliarden Tonnen auch korrekt) ist, in der zweiten Hälfte ebenfalls den Plural zu verwenden.

Andere Beispiele:

> Von meinem Apfelbaum werden jedes Jahr 500kg Äpfel produziert, von denen 300kg direkt zur Kelterei gebracht werden.

Die 500kg werden produziert, daher muss auch hier der Plural verwendet werden. Ebenso sind die 300kg ein Plural, daher *werden* sie zur Kelterei gefahren.

Die Frage ist immer, wie das Subjekt des Satzes gestaltet ist, bzw. auf was sich das Verb überhaupt bezieht. In folgendem Beispiel wären wir wieder beim Singular:

> In Großbritannien fallen jedes Jahr 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll an, wovon mit 9,4 Milliarden Tonnen weniger als die Hälfte recycelt wird.

Das *recycelt werden* bezieht sich hier auf *weniger als die Hälfte*. Dass dies in diesem Fall mehrere Milliarden Tonnen sind, ist für die Frage ob Singular oder Plural nicht relevant.

Ebenso in diesem Beispiel:

> In Großbritannien wird jedes Jahr die unglaubliche Menge von 23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Müll erzeugt.

Hier ist der Singular korrekt, denn es wird sich auf "die unglaubliche Menge" bezogen. Klar, die Menge sind in diesem Fall 23,5 Mrd. Tonnen, aber *die Menge* ist als Satzteil trotzdem Singular.

---

Aus aktuellem Anlass: Gerade auf Heise lese ich folgenden Satz:

> SketchUp Make und Pro läuft unter Windows und Mac OS X und steht auch mit deutscher Bedienoberfläche zum Download bereit.

Das ist nicht korrekt. Denn hier wird sich auf zwei Programme bezogen, nämlich SketchUp Make und SketchUp Pro. Daher müsste es korrekt heißen:

> SketchUp Make und Pro laufen (beide) unter Windows und Mac OS X und stehen (beide) auch mit deutscher Bedienoberfläche zum Download bereit.

Comment: Bei Heise scheinen sie es nie besonders genau mit der Sprache zu nehmen.

Comment: Die Antwort trifft den Punkt nicht; zur Demonstration ersetze man _Äpfel_ durch _Mehl_, und der Singular wird möglich: _In meiner Mühle wird jeden Tag 500 kg Mehl produziert, wovon 300 kg direkt in die benachbarte Bäckerei gebracht wird._

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Nun, das ist die eine Auffassung, aber die andere ist ebenso gültig. Manche folgen der einen, manche der anderen, die meisten schwanken. (Und zwei Randbemerkungen: „von denen es keine Pluralform gibt“ ist nicht zutreffend, es gibt _Mehle_, wie auch _Stähle_, _Wässer_ usw.; und „stehen eigentlich sogar im Genitiv“ ist schlicht Quark.)

Comment: @chirlu: Im Lateinischen stünde tatsächlich Genitiv. Obschon das im Deutschen durchaus ungebräuchlich ist, finde ich persönlich es passend und zulässig.

Comment: @bsumirak: Es geht nicht darum, welche anderen Sprachen da möglicherweise Genitiv, Lokativ oder sonst etwas benutzen. Wenn **im Deutschen** von _500 Kilogramm Mehl_ die Rede ist, ist das eindeutig *kein* Genitiv; sonst würde es nämlich _500 Kilogramm Mehls_ heißen.

Comment: @chirlu: Finde ich auch nicht falsch. Partitive Apposition. Soll allerdings laut [dieser Quelle](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Partitive-33869) aus der Antwort von Em1 zur Duplikat-Frage lediglich im Plural gebräuchlich sein. Ich votiere, da Sprache ja dynamisch ist, für Zulässigkeit auch im Singular.

Comment: @bsumirak: Geht alles völlig am Thema vorbei. Ich sage: In _500 kg Mehl_ ist _Mehl_ kein Genitiv. Dann kannst du mir nicht mit dem Argument (ob nun zutreffend oder nicht) widersprechen, man könne aber _500 kg Mehls_ sagen.

Comment: Gut, die Sache mit dem Genitiv hätte ich lassen sollen. Ich bleibe dabei: sobald eine Quantifizierung des Subjekts stattfindet wie in meinem Beispiel der Äpfel oder in Deinem Beispiel mit Mehl, gibt es keine Wahl mehr. Bzw. ist mir wurscht, ob Mehl, Äpfel, Müll oder was auch immer produziert werden. Es wird eine bestimmte Anzahl von etwas produziert und diese bestimmt auch, ob das Verb im Sing. oder Pl. steht.

Answer (score 2):

In der [Quelle](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mengenangabe-49575) von Em1, in der Antwort zu [»Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.«](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/eine-halbe-million-h%C3%A4user-wurde-zerst%C3%B6rt) steht:

> **Mengenangabe im Plural mit Nomen im Singular » Verb im Plural (o. Singular)**
>
> Wenn die Mengenangabe im Plural und das ihr folgenden Nomen im
>   Singular stehen, steht das Verb meistens im Plural, seltener im
>   Singular. Steht das Verb im Plural, richtet es sich nach dem
>   grammatikalischen Subjekt. Steht das Verb im Singular richtet es sich
>   sinngemäß nach dem inhaltlichen Subjekt.
>
> Achtung: Für viele gilt hier die Verwendung des Singulars als nicht
>   standardsprachlich!

Danach könnte man im Ausnahmefall das Verb im singular verwenden, allerdings geben alle angegebenen Beispiele den Plural als Standard an.

Bei "23,5 Milliarden Tonnen Hausmüll" ist "23,5 Milliarden Tonnen" das grammatikalische Subjekt, und Müll das inhaltliche Subjekt. Das Verb sollte sich also eigentlich nach dem grammatikalischen Subjekt richten und plural sein.

Falls ich mich nach dem inhaltliche Subjekt "Müll" richten würde, würde ich trotzdem anzweifeln, dass "Müll" im Singular gemeint wäre. Es gibt ja einfach keine grammatikalische Pluralform und inhaltlich wird deutlich, dass es eine große Menge Müll ist.

Comment: Eine Randnotiz noch. "Der Müll **wurde** entsorgt". Das Wort erfordert den Singular, daher rührt auch die Problematik. In "23,5 Mrd. Tonnen Müll" ist es eine Apposition. Stell dir folgende Unterhaltung vor: "Wieviel Müll wurde entsorgt? — 23,5 Mrd. Tonnen wurden entsorgt." Ohne Kontext würdest du auf die Antwort mit "23,5 Mrd Tonnen was?" reagieren, und daran erkennst du, dass es nur ein Zusatz ist, aber für das Subjekt grammatikalisch irrelevant.

Comment: Da Müll aber prinzipiell immer im Singular vorkommt und i.d.R. egal ist, wieviel Müll da ist (jede beliebige Menge an Müll entspricht "1 Müll"), ist im Kopf auch 23,5 Mrd. Tonnen Müll eben "1 Müll", und insofern ist es inhaltlich eben ein Subjekt im Singular.

Comment: Meine Sichtweise darauf ist eben, dass *23,5 Mrd. Tonnen* von irgendwas produziert wurden. Für die grammatikalische Struktur des Satzes ist mir wurscht was, ich weiß das 23,5 Mrd. Tonnen von einer Sache mehr als 1 sind. :-)

Comment: @Em1: Es ist Müll, nicht 1 Müll.