# Warum verwendet man (meistens) keinen Plural bei Größeneinheiten?

Tags: usage, grammatical-number

Beim Bezahlen an der Kasse ist mir aufgefallen, dass wir "5 Euro" statt "5 Euros" sagen, obwohl es sich hierbei um mehrere Euro**s** handelt.

Einige weitere Größeneinheiten verhalten sich ähnlich und nutzen den Singular. Wir sagen

- 5 Gramm statt 5 Gramme
- 5 Byte  statt 5 Bytes

Eine Ausnahme wäre jedoch zum Beispiel die Einheit Tonnen. Wir sagen

- 5 Tonnen statt 5 Tonne

Gibt es einen Grund, warum hier nicht der Plural (konsistent) genutzt wird?

Comment: Ich glaub, da hats schon mal eine Frage gegeben, aber frag mich nicht wo …

Comment: Der Plural von Volt ist nicht Volts sondern ebenfalls Volt. Bei Euro gilt, dass sowohl Euros als auch Euro gültige Pluralformen sind (bei DWDS steht zu Euro-Pluralform explizit: *als Währungseinheit in Verbindung mit Zahlen*). Bei Byte laut DWDS ebenfalls Plural Byte (Zusatz: *als Mengenangabe*).

Comment: Interessant auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter#Sprachgebrauch

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30269/101-000-000-in-worten/30285#30285

Comment: Beim € muss man unterscheiden zwischen den Sprachhütern und den €-Hütern: Erstere lassen in vielen europäischen Sprachen einen Plural zu, die Währungshüter haben allerdings definiert, dass es zum Euro keinen Plural gibt.

Comment: Und auch related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26767/tonnen-m%c3%bcll-plural-oder-singular

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar danke für den Hinweis. Ich werde Volt entfernen, da Plural und Singular sich nicht unterscheiden und somit für die Fragestellung weniger relevant sind

Comment: @tofro Naja, auf Englisch heißt es standardmäßig »ten euros«, während der Preis auf Deutsch »zehn Euro« sind; geht es aber um zehn Euromünzen ist »zehn Euros« richtig. Im Englischen wird dieser Unterschied schlicht nicht übertragen. Währungshüter haben aber natürlich keinen Einfluss auf die Grammatik.

Comment: @Jan Habe hier http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13551/€10-ten-euro-or-ten-euros eine schöne Antwort gefunden, die wiedergibt, dass die Situation sogar zwischen Irland (€-country) und UK (non-€-country) unterschiedlich ist ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalerweise werden werden Maßbezeichnungen bzw. Einheiten mit Zahlwörtern nicht flektiert:

> Morgen soll es minus 12 Grad bekommen.
>
> Meine Frau besitzt 10 Paar Schuhe.
>
> Der Preis von 2000 Euro für 75 Kilogramm war mir zu teuer.

Weibliche Bezeichnungen die auf –e enden werden allerdings sehr wohl gebeugt:

> Wir haben zwei Tasse**n** Kaffee getrunken.
>
> Das höchstzulässige Gesamtgewicht beträgt 38,5 Tonne**n**.

Comment: Ein weiteres Beispiel, das gebeugt wird: "Vier Messerspitzen"

Comment: Mir ist nicht klar, warum das Geschlecht ausschlaggebend sein soll.  Den Beispielen nach kann es genau so gut sein, dass die Einheiten pluralisiert werden, die auch einen Gegenstand bezeichnen.

Comment: @Dirk: Weil das bei anderen Geschlechtern, selbst wenn sie Gegenstände bezeichnen, nicht der Fall ist: das Stück, das Blatt, der Beutel ...

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%A4hlwort Eine kleine Liste von Maßeinheiten,die nicht flektiert werden.

Answer (score 5):

Die Frage nach dem »Warum?« hat im Zusammenhang mit Sprache fast immer die gleiche Antwort: Weil es sich so eingebürgert hat.

### Wie funktionieren Sprach-Regeln?

Es gibt wohldefinierte Regeln, die man in der Schule lernt, und mit deren Hilfe man eine Fremdsprache lernen kann. Das sind Regeln, die in Büchern stehen. Aber diese Regeln definieren nicht den ganz alltäglichen Gebrauch einer Sprache. Kinder, die noch nie in der Schule waren, beweisen es jeden Tag: Man kann verständlich sprechen und man kann andere verstehen, ohne je eine einzige Regel gelernt zu haben, und auch ohne eine einzige Regel formulieren zu können. Es ist in Wahrheit nämlich umgekehrt: Der alltägliche Gebrauch einer Sprache legt fest, welche Regeln man in die Bücher schreiben muss. Und weil sich die Sprache ständig ändert, müssen auch die Regeln von Zeit zu Zeit angepasst werden.

**Ein Beispiel:**
Als ich noch in die Schule ging sagte man »etwas ist sinnvoll« oder »etwas ergibt Sinn«. Niemand sagte »etwas macht Sinn«. Die Idee, *Sinn* sei etwas, das von einer Sache oder einem Vorgang hergestellt werden könne, erschien damals völlig absurd. Hätte ich als Schüler in den 1970er-Jahren den Satz »Essen macht Sinn weil man sonst verhungert« in einem Aufsatz geschrieben, wäre mir das aus gutem Grund als Fehler angerechnet worden, weil Sinn nichts ist, was durch den Vorgang, den man »Essen« nennt, hergestellt werden kann. Heute gehört »das macht Sinn« aber zum ganz alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch und stört niemanden mehr. Kein Lehrer würde heute darin einen Fehler sehen. Die Regel, die in den 1970er-Jahren die Konstruktion »das macht Sinn« verboten hat, gilt heute nicht mehr.

Auf diese Weise wandelt sich die Sprache in einem ständigen Prozess. Es ist der tatsächliche alltägliche Gebrauch, der diesen Wandel vorantreibt. Die Regeln, die man in Deutschbüchern nachlesen kann, sind nur der Versuch, die impliziten Regeln, nach denen die Menschen auf der Straße ihre Sätze bilden, explizit zu machen. Daher hinken diese Regeln in den Büchern immer dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch hinterher.

**Wie geht so eine Änderung vonstatten?**
Das ist recht einfach: Jemand verstößt gegen eine etablierte Sprachregel. Der häufigste Grund: Dieser Jemand beherrscht die Sprache nicht auf höchstem Niveau. Das können Kinder sein, aber auch Menschen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache sprechen, und unbewusst Elemente einer anderen Sprache in ihren Gebrauch der deutschen Sprache einbringen. So etwas ist zunächst ganz formal ein eindeutiger Fehler.

Aber andere, die das hören, finden möglicherweise an dieser anderen Art zu sprechen vielleicht Gefallen und ahmen sie nach. Das kann ganz bewusst erfolgen, viel häufiger geschieht das aber unbewusst. Der neue Sprecher merkt gar nicht, dass er selbst den Fehler eines anderen Sprechers wiederholt.

Dadurch vergrößert sich die Gruppe, die eine bestimmte Regel durch eine andere Regel ersetzt. In den meisten Fällen bleibt so etwas auf eine kleine Gruppe beschränkt, die dann wieder schrumpft, so dass am Ende alles wieder wie früher ist. Aber manchmal schließen sich immer mehr Menschen diesen neuen Art zu sprechen an. Das kann dann so weit gehen, das am Ende (fast) die gesamte Sprachgemeinschaft den Wechsel zur neuen Regel vollzogen hat. Spätestens dann ist es Zeit für die Autoren von Grammatikbüchern ihre Bücher zu überarbeiten.

### Was heißt das für den Gebrauch von Maßeinheiten?

Das bedeutet, dass die Mehrheit der Bevölkerung mitbekommen hat, dass ihre Mitmenschen Maßeinheiten meist im Singular verwenden. Daher machen sie es selbst genau so. Und weil aber doch manchmal Einheiten im Plural verwendet werden, sind viele Sprecher verunsichert und sie wissen nicht immer genau was richtig und was falsch ist. Und genau das ist der Grund, warum so viel Sprecher hier Fehler machen, wobei das Begriff »Fehler« nicht so streng gesehen werden darf. Es sind eher individuelle Variationen.

### Was sind nun die streng formalen Regeln für Maßeinheiten?

Dazu muss man erst mal definieren was eine Maßeinheit ist und was nicht.

Jemand sagt:

> Auf meinem Schreibtisch liegen **drei Euros**.

Damit ist gemeint, das drei Ein-Euro-Münzen auf dem Tisch liegen. Hier wird »Euro« nicht als Maßeinheit verwendet, sondern es sind damit ganz bestimmte Gegenstände gemeint. Weil es davon aber mehrere gibt, muss man hier die Mehrzahl verwenden.

> Auf meinem Konto liegen **drei Euro**.

Hier sind keine einzelne Münzen gemeint, die man aufheben und fallen lassen kann. Hier geht es um einen Geldbetrag, dessen Größe mit Hilfe einer Maßeinehit gemessen werden kann. Diese Einheit heißt »Euro« und besitzt keine Mehrzahl. (Ich betrachte hier »**Euro<sub>Münze</sub>**« und »**Euro<sub>Währungseinheit</sub>**« als zwei verschiedene Wörter)

Vielen ist auch unklar, welche Begriffe als Maßeinheiten verwendbar sind.

- Das sind natürlich die gesetzlichen und physikalischen Einheiten (Quadratkilometer, Joule, Minute, Dollar)
- Dann gibt es die historischen Einheiten (Klafter, Joch, Lot, Ballen)
- Aber im sprachlichen Sinn gelten auch ungenormte Größen als Maßeineit (Armlänge, Handvoll, Tasse)

Und das sind die Regeln:

1. Prinzipiell werden Maßeinheiten nicht flektiert wenn sie hinter Zahlwörtern stehen

   > Mit **20 Euro** wirst du nicht weit kommen.
   >   Irene hat gestern **drei Paar** Schuhe gekauft.
2. Wenn die folgenden Bedingungen zutreffen, darf die Einheit flektiert werden.

   - Eine Präposition bewirkt, dass das die Einheit im Dativ steht.
   - Es handelt sich um eine ungefähre und um eine laienhafte Aussage, also um keine technisch exakte Angabe.
   - Die gezählte oder gemessene Größe steht nicht hinter der Einheit.

   Das ist also erlaubt:

   > Ab einer Entfernung von ca. **drei Metern** sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Aber das muss man nicht machen. Auch das ist daher erlaubt:

   > Ab einer Entfernung von ca. **drei Meter** sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Hier darf aber nicht flektiert werden:

   > Ab **drei Meter** Entfernung sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Grund: Die gemessene Größe (*Entfernung*) steht hinter der Einheit.
3. Einheiten, die weiblich sind und auf e enden, müssen flektiert werden.

   > Die Tonne - Drei **Tonnen** Sand liegen auf dem LKW.
   >   Die Krone - Der Eintritt kostete 30 **Kronen**.
   >   Die Minute - Ich warte hier schon seit 15 **Minuten**.
4. Einheiten, mit denen Zeit gemessen wird, verwendet man immer im Plural.

   > Walters Alter beträgt **37 Jahre**.
   >   Das dauert nun schon **14 Tage**.

Answer (score -3):

Alle deine Bespiele sind im deutschen nicht eindeutig.
Byte(s), Euro(s), Gramm(e), 
Alle diese Wörter haben zwei Pluralformen. Gebräuchlich sind jedoch die Formen die dem Singular gleichen.

Also nutzen wir schon konsistent den Plural, dieser ist nur nicht auf den ersten Blick erkennbar :)

Als Quelle diente der Duden.

Comment: @Iris: Also haben die DOCH 2 Pluralformen. Das hast du ja selber geschrieben.
Nur wird die andere nicht bei Zahlwörtern genutzt...

Comment: Wenn du deinem Link folgst, dann scrollst du ja nach unten zur Sektion Grtammatik.
In dieser Tabelle ist für jeden der vier Fälle der Singular und das Plural angegeben. 
Und bei Plural stehen zwei Wörter. Diese kann man beide verwenden.
Das was über der Tabelle steht, bedeutet dass bei einer Angabe mit einer bestimmten Menge der Singular verwendet wird und bei einer unbestimmten Menge (viele Gramm(e), mehrere Gramm(e)) können beiden Varianten verwendet werden.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob ich dieses Wiktionary als Quelle für einen Beleg akzeptieren kann. Vor Allem GEGEN den Duden. 
Ich habe beim Recherchieren der Quelln unterschiedliche Angaben gefunden.
Jedoch setze ich auf das im Duden Angegebene.

Ich habe in meine Antwort geschrieben, dass ich den Duden als Quelle nutzte.
Es ist anscheinend ein heikles Thema ;)

Comment: Bei Wiktionary sind nicht immer beide Formen als Plural gegeben und Duden sagt bei _Plural Bytes <aber: eine Million Bytes oder Byte>_. Deutsch kann echt verwirrend sein. ^^

Comment: also gibt es dort nur eine Pluralform, es sei denn es wird eine bestimmte Menge angegeben, dann gibt es zwei. Ja okay. Also ist es irgendwie nicht falsch und nicht richtig? =)

Comment: 1) *Gramme* habe ich noch nie gehört – hast du eine Quelle dafür? 2) ob ich »zehn Euro« oder »zehn Euros« sage, macht einen Unterschied. Ersteres kann ein Schein sein, zweiteres nicht.

Comment: @Jan: 1) Mehrfach in den Kommentaren vor deinem :)                             2)  hast du eine Quelle für diese Aussage?