# Physical units Singular/Plural

Tags: grammatical-number

Many physical units in German seem to have identical singular/plural forms. For example: 1 Meter, 2 Meter... At the moment the only exception that comes to mind are units of time "1 Sekunde, 2 Sekunden..." (and "Lichtjahr" which gramatically would be the same)

- Is there a reason for this?
- If I say "2 Meter", do I use the plural form of Meter?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34208/warum-verwendet-man-meistens-keinen-plural-bei-größeneinheiten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about countable vs. uncountable quantities. German speaking academics of the 19th century settled on treating all physical units uncountable. It makes some sense as most of these units are named after individual scienticists and *there ain't more than one Newton.* *Meter* and *Gramm* are uncountable just to fit the general rule.

It doesn't apply to time because people counted the time before. It doesn't apply to old measures as Meilen (miles) either, because people used that before.

Comment: Is 'Tonne' an old unit or an exception? Because it's 'eine Tonne, zwei Tonnen...'

Comment: Es ist eine weibliche Bezeichnung, die auf –e endet. Diese werden idR gebeugt (eine _Meile_, eine _Tasse_, eine _Tonne_). Im übrigen glaube ich nicht, dass diese Regeln erst seit Einführung des metrischen Systems gelten. Auch andere historische Einheiten, die zuvor verwendet wurden, wurden nicht gebeugt (_Joch, Fuß, Pfund_, letztlich auch _Stück_), außer sie waren weiblich auf -e (_Elle_).

Comment: On the other hand in English you do have 60 Watts and other plural forms of names.

Comment: @Iris: Tonne is an old unit. It was in use when scholars began to define old units in terms of their new units.

Comment: Are you sure "Meter" is uncountable? Because the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Meter) clearly says that the plural is also "Meter". Especially since it's "zwei Meilen", "zwei Lichtjahre" etc.

Comment: You are right, some people say *auf einem Gebäude von 50 Meter**n** Höhe*, so it's ambigous.