# Maß- und Mengeeinheiten ohne Pluralkongruenz mit Zahlwort

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich bin neulich auf folgenden Satz getroffen: "diese Waffe hat 17 Schuss". 
Offensichtlich verhält sich das Wort "Schuss" hier analog zu "Gramm", d.h. es wird nicht flektiert in die Pluralform, sondern bewahrt seine Grundform. 
Ist das fachsprachlich oder gilt das für die allgemeine Sprache auch?
Welche Wörter verhalten sich sonst noch so? Wenn eine Maschine fähig ist, 5 Fahrten zu machen, würde man auch da sagen, dass sie "5 Fahrt" hat?
NS: Funktioniert so für Schlücke. "5 Schluck Wasser" usw.

Comment: Verwandt: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34208/warum-verwendet-man-meistens-keinen-plural-bei-gr%C3%B6%C3%9Feneinheiten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gilt die Regel:

> Bei Maßeinheiten, Mengenbezeichnungen, Währungen und Ähnlichen, die Maskulina oder Neutra sind, wird bei Zahlenangaben kein Plural verwendet.

Siehe [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Ma%C3%9Feinheiten_und_Mengenbezeichnungen) bzw. Quelle dort: "Duden – Die Grammatik", 8. Auflage, Seite 175ff.

Weitere Beispiele stehen dort. "17 Schuss" fällt ebenso unter diese Regel, da es als Maßeinheit gebraucht wird. Es verhält sich also tatsächlich so wie mit "Gramm". Das gilt nicht nur fachsprachlich, sondern allgemein. Zum Beispiel hat auch ein Schiff umgangssprachlich "20 Mann Besatzung". (Ob es sich dabei tatsächlich nur um Männer handelt, sei dahingestellt.)

Das Beispiel mit der Maschine kann ich sprachlich (so) nicht nachvollziehen. Aber nein, von "5 Fahrt" würde man nicht sprechen, denn "Fahrt" ist keine Maßeinheit. (Auch nicht "5 Flug", wenngleich Flug männlich ist.) "Schluck" fungiert hingegen schon als Maßeinheit – das ist so korrekt. Die Abgrenzung ist sicherlich nicht immer nur mit Logik zu erklären. Da muss, zum Teil zumindest, der Sprachgebrauch herhalten.

Comment: @Janka hat übrigens oben eine interessante Ausnahme, "Da sind noch vier Freispiele auf dem Flipper" - und das obwohl Freispiel Neutrum ist.

Comment: Das sehe ich nicht so eindeutig ... Wenn ein Spielautomat 4 Freispiele hat, ist das einer Waffe mit "4 Schuss" doch ähnlich, oder?

Comment: Danke für Deinen Beitrag! Die Duden Grammatik fand ich sehr hilfreich. Allerdings wird da vieles nicht aufgelistet, auch "Schuss" nicht. Fallan Dir vllt. sonst noch Wörter ein, die so funktionieren?

Answer (score 1):

Manchmal steht die Maßeinheit im Singular, manchmal im Singular oder Plural, je nachdem, ob ein oder mehrere Dinge gezählt werden. Warum? Keiner weiß es.

> Drei Bier, bitte!

*Bier* ist hier eindeutig eine Maßeinheit.

> Drei Biere, bitte! – Drei unterschiedliche, oder was?

*Biere* wurde als Gattungsbegriff verstanden.

> In der Waffe sind noch fünf Schuss.

*Schuss* ist auch hier wieder eindeutig als Maßeinheit gebraucht. Man kann noch fünf Schüsse abgeben.

> In der Waffe sind noch fünf Schüsse.

Was sollen *Schüsse* in einer Waffe eigentlich sein? Man kann noch fünf Schüsse abgeben, aber sie befinden sich nicht in der Waffe. Da sind fünf Patronen drin.

Zugegeben, dieser Satz kommt vermutlich auch beim einen oder anderen Autor mit *Schüsse* statt *Schuss* vor.

> Da sind noch zwei Fahrt**en** im Autoscooter.
>
> Da sind noch vier Freispiel**e** auf dem Flipper.
>
> Ich hätte gerne drei Kugel**n** Eis.

Warum? Keiner weiß es!

Comment: "Drei Bier, bitte!" - das könnte eine Weglassung sein. 'Drei Mal Bier, bitte'

Comment: Bei Fahrten und Kugeln könnte es daran liegen, dass die Wörter weiblich sind. Wie hier erwähnt https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34210/9739

Comment: Würde das auch noch für Einsätze funktionieren? Oder Gänge? 
Wie etwa "die Maschine hat 5 Gang", im Sinne, kann 5 Mal verwendet werden.

Übrigens @Janka, wenn Du die Info über das Geschlecht eines Maßwortes als ein entscheidender Faktor reinschreibst, würde deine Antwort meine Frage fast zu 100%  beantworten! ;)

Comment: Ich denke aber nicht, dass es am Geschlecht hängt. *Das Bier* – *Das Spiel*. Oder ganz profan *die Uhr*.

Comment: Guter Punkt! Was für ein Beispiel mit Spiel fällt dir da ein?

Comment: Hatten wir doch schon mit dem *Freispiel*.

Comment: Stimmt, ist halt die Frage, ob wir Freispiel tatsächlich zu "Maßeinheiten, Mengenbezeichnungen, Währungen und Ähnlichen" zählen können.  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53341/ma%c3%9f-und-mengeeinheiten-ohne-pluralkongruenz-mit-zahlwort#comment129704_53344
Falls ja,  dann ob es 1) eine Ausnahme aus der sonst gültigen Regel ist oder 2) die Regel zunichte macht